# Is there a way to make a triangular HR?

Tags: css

Is there a way to make an HR that's basically a left to right triangle? So, you might have a 7 px base on the left, but it narrows to 1 px (centered vertically) on the right?

I've tried doing this with linear-gradients, but I can't get it to do 2 two-dimensional gradients.

Comment: Perhaps this might help https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: this will probably help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work/49696143#49696143 ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using clip-path.

```css
hr {
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  border: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

See [clipath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/)